# How not to split a single word in two lines in jQuery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am using jQuery css and jQuery like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

I am using dialog box like this:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm-share" title="Genalytics" style="display:none;">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>File you selected has been already shared with that user.</p>
</div>
```

The words are splitted in dialog box like this:

```
File you selected has been already sha
red with that user.
```

I don't want the word to split? How can I fix this?

Comment: try these in your CSS ....    white-space: pre-line; word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also customize your dialog the way you want, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GnpQ8/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-confirm-share").dialog({
        width: 250,
        height: 120,       
        modal: true,
        resizable: false
    });
});
```

### And add these css,

```
#dialog-confirm-share p{
    word-break:keep-all;
    word-wrap:normal;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: you want it in a single line?

Comment: add this css n see, #dialog-confirm-share p{
    word-break:keep-all;
    word-wrap:normal;
    white-space:normal;
}